# Как сгруппировать по нескольким колонкам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, group-by

Есть датасет `df` с колонками `person, year,    sum_of_purchase`. В датасете может быть много строк - когда один 'person' в один 'year' тратил разные суммы.

Надо сделать: 1) новую колонку `df['mean_sum_of_purchases_this_year']`; 2) в этой колонке должна быть средняя сумма всех покупок этого 'person' за тот год, который будет в той же строке.

Вот так нахожу среднюю сумму всех трат одного 'person' за все годы:

```
df["mean_sum_of_purchase_all_years"] = 
    df.person.map(df.groupby("person").sum_of_purchase.mean())
```

Понимаю, что это тема 'groupby multiple times'.

Но что брать - 'map' или 'apply', и как применить?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
df["mean_sum_of_purchase_all_years"] = \
    df.groupby(["person", "year"])["sum_of_purchase"].transform("mean")
```

Comment: У меня ещё вопрос по тому же игрушечному датасету.
Как к имеющемуся условия добавить ещё одно - фильтр по "sum_of_purchase"? 
Пусть например "> 250". Т.е. все покупки конкретного 'person' за конкретный 'year' с указанным фильтром.
Пытаюсь применять loc, iloc, query, isin - в комбинации с groupby не работают.

Comment: @БорисМирский, жду [mcve]... ;)

Comment: `df[df.sum_of_purchase > 250]` и дальше уже `groupby`

Comment: @CrazyElf, тут все зависит от желаемого результата... Что делать со строками, не подпадающими под это условие? Поэтому я не отвечаю на вопрос, пока не увижу небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных и ожидаемый результат 

Comment: @CrazyElf - то что надо, благодарю!

Comment: @MaxU - ещё раз спасибо!!